SetTimeout does not work with recursion. What am I doing wrong?
I need a function to print numbers from 1 to 10 every ms using recursion.
My function prints numbers ​​from 2 to infinity, probably, although the condition for exiting the recursion is written. What am I doing wrong?
 function printNumbers2(from, to) {
  let number = from;

  if (number == to) {
    return number;
  } else {
    return setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(number);
      number++;
      printNumbers2(number);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

console.log(printNumbers2(1, 10));

Result:
Timeout {
  _idleTimeout: 1000,
  _idlePrev: [TimersList],
  _idleNext: [TimersList],
  _idleStart: 15,
  _onTimeout: [Function (anonymous)],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: null,
  _destroyed: false,
  [Symbol(refed)]: true,
  [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2,
  [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1
}
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13


Note setTimeout accepts additional arguments that are bound to the function's parameters.
Some other suggestions:

avoid mixed return type of number and timer
avoid mutation where possible
localize console.log so caller doesn't need to print last number



function printNumbers(from, to) {
  if (from > to) return
  console.log(from)
  setTimeout(printNumbers, 1000, from + 1, to)
}

printNumbers(1, 10)



You could express it using async..await using a sleep function, but this has the risk of overflowing the stack if the range is significantly large  -


async function printNumbers(from, to) {
  if (from > to) return
  console.log(from)
  await sleep(1000)
  printNumbers(from + 1, to)
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

printNumbers(1, 10)



Expressing as an async generator, we can remove the console.log side effect and allow the caller to decide. Because the function no longer prints, we just call it numbers -


async function* numbers(from, to) {
  let n = from
  while (n <= to) {
    yield n++
    await sleep(1000)
  }
}

async function main() {
  let sum = 0
  for await (const n of numbers(1, 10)) {
    sum += n
    console.log(`n: ${n}, sum: ${sum}`)
  }
  return sum
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

main().then(console.log).catch(console.error)



You could express the generator recursively, but this has the risk of overflowing the stack if the range is significantly large -


async function* numbers(from, to) {
  if (from > to) return
  yield from
  await sleep(1000)
  yield *numbers(from + 1, to)
}

async function main() {
  let sum = 0
  for await (const n of numbers(1, 10)) {
    sum += n
    console.log(`n: ${n}, sum: ${sum}`)
  }
  return sum
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

main().then(console.log).catch(console.error)




You forgot to pass in your "to" parameter in your recursive call:
function printNumbers2(from, to) {
  let number = from;

  if (number == to) {
    return number;
  } else {
    return setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(number);
      number++;
      printNumbers2(number, to); // <-- pass in your "to" parameter
    }, 1000);
  }
}

console.log(printNumbers2(1, 10));


As Julien Rheinbach noted you forgot to pass to in the timed call, so number == to will never occur.
FYI, your code can be simplified. Here is a cleaned up version, adding a time variable allowding varying the timeout value.
Edit setTimeout: use callback parameters (as pointed to by Mulan)


printNumbersTimed(1, 5, 1);

function printNumbersTimed(from, to, time = 0.5) {
  const isDone = from === to;
  console.clear() ?? console.log(isDone ?
    `all done, your number is ${from}` :
    `now at: ${from}`);

  return isDone || 
    setTimeout(printNumbersTimed, time * 1000, from + 1, to, time);
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}



